# What happens if I pocket both players' last C/m and the Striker in one shot?

Tags: carrom

Suppose I pot the last red C/m, the last white C/m and the Striker together. The Queen isn't on the board. Is that a win for me or do I return the C/m with a penalty?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the ICF rules](http://icf-media.beepworld.de/laws-of-carrom.htm), it's a loss for you.

Depending on who covered the Queen, your opponent will get 1-3 points, +1 for the Striker, and +1 if it was an improper stroke.

> 110. a) If a player pockets the last C/m of his own and of his opponent together with the Striker by a proper stroke he shall lose the Board by one point, if the Queen has been covered by him. One additional point for the pocketed Striker shall be awarded if demanded by the opponent.
>
>      b) If a player pockets the last C/m of his own and of his opponent together with the Striker by an improper stroke, he shall lose the Board by one point, if the Queen has been covered by him. Two additional points shall be awarded, if demanded by the opponent.
> 111. a) If a player pockets the last C/m of his own and of his opponent together with the Striker by a proper stroke, he shall lose the Board by 3 points, if the Queen has been covered by the opponent. If the score of the opponent is 22 or more, he shall get one point. One additional point shall be awarded, if demanded by the opponent.
>
>      b) If a player pockets the last C/m of his own and of his opponent together with the Striker by an improper stroke he shall lose the Board by 3 points, if  the Queen has been covered by the opponent. If the score of the opponent is 22 or more he shall get one point. Two additional points shall be awarded, if demanded by the opponent.